# Widget is not update in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to fetch data from web service and display in widget.

I do following code but widget is not update after fetching data. I have search lot of but didn't get any help.

want to fetch data from server and display in widget. I got data but it not display on widget. where I am wrong?

please see below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minWidth="292dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400"
  >
</appwidget-provider>


public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    ArrayList<String> aryThumbnail = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryId = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryLike = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aryTime = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context;
    RemoteViews views;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new AsyncAction().execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        this.context = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending);
            Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

            PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, configIntent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, configPendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            callRecentVideo();
            // populateListItem();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
    }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private String callRecentVideo() {
        String result;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        Function c = new Function();
        result = c.getString(c.link.toString() + "recent_videos");

        try {

            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            String getStatus = json_data.getString("status");
            Log.e("status", getStatus);
            String getError = json_data.getString("ERROR");

            Log.e("Error", getError);

            String getReason = json_data.getString("Reason");
            // Log.e("Reason", getReason);
            if (getError == null) {
                // return "Unable to SignIn, please try again.";
                return getReason;
            }
            String getDetails = json_data.getString("videos");
            // Log.e("videos", getDetails);

            JSONArray aryVideo = new JSONArray(getDetails);

            for (int i = 0; i <= aryVideo.length(); i++) {
                String id = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                String channel_id = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "channel_id");
                String videos_title = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "videos_title");
                String description = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "description");
                String thumbnail = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "thumbnail");
                String url = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
                String likes = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString("likes");
                String uploadtime = aryVideo.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "uploadtime");
                aryId.add(id.toString());

                aryThumbnail.add(thumbnail.toString());
                aryUrl.add(url.toString());
                aryTitle.add(videos_title.toString());

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.title, videos_title);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Try to do the setTextViewText() call in onPostExecute.

Comment: can you say me what's error?

Comment: publishProgress(""+String.valueOf(msum)); in doInBakground

Comment: Sorry, I experenced now that you can do it `inDoInBackground`. But you have to call also `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()`.